# Django - ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'

Tags: django

I can see alot of related questions to mine and when i check them out, from what i can see my code should be working, but im getting the below error?

models:

```
class Circuits(models.Model):    
    site_data = models.ForeignKey(SiteData,verbose_name="Site")   
    order_no = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name="Order No")
    expected_install_date = models.DateField()
    install_date = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    circuit_type = models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=settings.CIRCUIT_CHOICES)    
    circuit_preference = models.CharField(max_length=20,verbose_name="Circuit Preference",choices=settings.CIRCUIT_PREFERENCE,blank=True,null=True)
    circuit_speed = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    circuit_bearer = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)

class CircuitMaintenance(models.Model): 
    circuit = models.ForeignKey(Circuits,verbose_name="Circuit", related_name='maintenance')
    ref = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name="Ref No")
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
```

error

```
circuits = Circuits.objects.filter(site_data__id=1)
for i in Circuits.maintenance.all():
 print i
AttributeError: 'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'
```

EDIT:
amended with lower case c still getting error:

```
>>> from sites.models import Circuits
>>> circuits = Circuits.objects.filter(site_data__id=1)
>>> for i in circuits.maintenance.all():
...  print i
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'maintenance'
>>>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to used your variable `circuits`

```
circuits = Circuits.objects.filter(site_data__id=1)
for cm in circuits:
    maintenances = cm.maintenance.all()
    for maintenance in maintenances:
         print(maintenance )
```

If you don't define a `related_name`, you can do:

```
circuits.circuitmaintenance_set.all() :
```

Comment: ahh yes! i put capital c!

Comment: I edited my code. You need to loop on queryset. Like this you have Circuits object.

Comment: `Circuits.objects.filter(maintenance__site_data__id=1)` should do the trick.
Hope it helps :)

Comment: @FredChevitarese What if I dont have `site_data_id`. I want an inner join. `Circuits.circuitmaintenance_set.filter(status=1)` doesnt work. it says no filter attribute for reverse foreign key